# Alternatives to XMLHttpRequest with HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xmlhttprequest

I want to, as much as I can, build my website with only HTML/CSS. Is it possible to do some of the great things XMLHttpRequest does with pure HTML/CSS? For example load HTML from a URL into a div:

```
$("div").load("path/to/my/html")
```

But only with HTML/CSS?

Comment: thinks that's called iframe

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come is [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)s.

In most cases, you are better off with regular links.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need javascript for anything dynamic like that.

Answer (score 1):

Neither HTML nor CSS are programming or scripting languages.
HTML is a markup language, and CSS is a style sheet language to format HTML.
If you need some kind of dynamic behavior in your web site, your best bet is to use Javascript.

There are some HTML tags that allow loading content, some have already pointed out [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp). It might suit your needs, but in general, you might want to at least include some JS in your project to make it easier to deal with (unless, of course, it's part of the requirements of your project not to use JS). Good luck!